# Double spacing file using sed in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am new to shell scripting and I used the following code to double space a file (input file is a parameter):

```
sed G $input_file >> $input_file
```

The problem is, if the content of my original file is:

```
Hi
My name is
```

My double-spaced file is:

```
Hi
My name is
Hi

My name is
```

Is there something else I need to add in the shell script so that my file will only be:

```
Hi

My name is
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the append operator (`>>`), which appends to the file in question. That being said, you can't generally operate on and output to the same file with `>` in bash, either. For `sed`'s specific case, you can use the `-i` option (depending on version and platform):

```
sed -i G $input_file
```

That should edit your file "in place", if your version has that option. I say "in place" because I'm pretty sure it *actually* creates a new file and moves it back on top of the first one for you (inode is different). If not, you'd output to a separate file, and move the file back:

```
sed G ${input_file} > ${input_file}.bak
mv ${input_file}.bak ${input_file}
```

Comment: I had used (>) before but it didn't work, thanks for clearing this up for me!